# .bvh set parent with automatic weights issue

Tags: blender

I'm working on a blender project trying to import the the bvh and map it to mesh. As shown in the below figure I've been able to import the mesh and then imported the .bvh file. The first question is, under the .bvh file in the menu on the top right as shown in the below figures, there are two files under the object, one is named as the same name of the .bvh file and the other is named `Pose`. When I click on the 01_01 even after fitting the human on top of it this is what happens:
[image] 
so as seen the armature and the human are separated.

And when I choose the `pose` one this is what happens:
[image]

so anyway, after that I select the human mesh then `shift` the armature and then click `ctrl+p` and choose `parent with automatic weights` but this is the result:
[image]

I have no idea why this is happening? I'd be very thankful if anyone could please advise how to fix this. Because if I played the file after this is the a snapshot of the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that all the vertices are not being assigned to the armature when you reparent the mesh. 
Either you need to go into edit mode and manually assign the remaining vertices to there proper groups or...
...if the bvh armature has the same amount of bones as the makehuman armature does, then try scaling the bvh armature up to the size of the makehuman armature. Then go and add Copy Location/Rotation/Scale constraints to each of the bones to have it copy the same bone on the other armature.
Iv'e done it before and it works. Just takes awhile tho.